# Visual Studio Code's terminal does not work

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

The terminal of my Visual Studio Code does not work. When I click on the terminal, this error is coming up:

> The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred
> during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 1260).

Also, my operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (File not found: )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321709/the-terminal-process-failed-to-launch-a-native-exception-occurred-during-launch)

Answer (score 7):

1. Ctrl + Shift +P
2. Select "Preferences: Open User Settings"
3. Write "terminal" in the search box
4. Search for "Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows"
5. Set value to "Command Prompt"

[image]

Comment: {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
}