# VS Code won't open terminal when trying to launch Python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It just seems like I can't open a terminal in VS Code. Every time I try to open a terminal, it gives me this error:

[image: the error i encounter]

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

I tried reinstalling VS Code but it didn't work. I also tried disabling all extensions except python extension but it didn't work too.

Comment: here should be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979932/visual-studio-codes-terminal-does-not-work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code's terminal does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66979932/visual-studio-codes-terminal-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Ctrl + Shift +P
2. Select "Preferences: Open User Settings"
3. Write "terminal" in the search box
4. Search for "Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows"
5. Set value to "Command Prompt"

[Helpful Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxNi.png)

Comment: you are an absolute life saver! thank you! after months of roaming the internet for an answer i finally fixed it !!! thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer I'd very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score -3):

Ctrl + Shift +P
Select "Preferences: Open User Settings"
Write "terminal" in the search box
Search for "Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows"
Set value to "Command Prompt"
or to "Powershell"

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer is not essentially different from @Raylo's answer, and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers, either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether, this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful, not scattered/duplicated.