# Is it possible to run code in Visual Studio Code without a shell?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My school has blocked `cmd` and Powershell due to security concerns. Unfortunately for me, this prevents VSC from running code! I love using VSC, so I'm wondering if there's any way I can continue to use it without the powershell or cmd terminals.

Comment: Run a tiny VM from a USB pen.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072535/using-visual-studio-code-without-access-to-powershell) answers your question.

Comment: Maybe if you can find a terminal emulator to substitute CMD or PowerShell. But from the description of the user policy could an application actually be run on those computers?

Comment: @cigien that wouldn't work either, since cmd/PS are denied at the Group Policy level. OP would need to install an alternative (which considering that they are blocked in the first place, I don't think the admin would be jazzed about). Imagine for the OP system that cmd.exe and powershell.exe don't exist at all.

Comment: As per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), Questions that asks about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are fine for Stack Overflow. This is about how to set up or run Visual Studio Code without a command prompt or PowerShell. Which is exactly the case that is mentioned in the help page.

Comment: Just to reiterate what has been suggested above; if the policy blocks Powershell and CMD, finding a way to circumvent that policy is probably also a policy violation.

Comment: @tripleee methinks it's not the OP's case - they just want to run a debugger in VSC :) But a good reminder nonetheless