# I get "powershell.exe does not exist" when I run my program in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Can you guys help me with this error? This always happens when I try to run my code.

> The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" does not exist.

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: Did you install Powershell?

Comment: Yes, several times. I also tried reinstalling it, but always the same problem

Comment: If you paste the path into file explorer does it exist in that folder?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: i'm using the Win 10 pro

Comment: have you read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-vs-code-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it doesnt, i think i was installing it in the wrong path OMG