# VSCode won't launch terminal / run program

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to open the terminal in VSCode, I've been getting the error "The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "C:\Windows\Sysnative\cmd.exe" does not exist".

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jbcP.png)

The command line directory is still C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, not sure what to do from here, has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27915 ?

The issue recommends setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"` somewhere in your configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-vs-code-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch