# Failed to launch debuggee in terminal

Tags: java, terminal, command-line-interface

When i am trying to open a new terminal in my visual studio code window. My terminal and i am seeing this message "Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. Reason: Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. Reason: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: timeout"

it shows me open launch.json file. i dont know what to do in that file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to uncheck this box in the settings and it fixed my issue

My Java Version:

- java 19.0.2 2023-01-17
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
  19.0.2+7-44)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)

[image]

Comment: Worked for me, I don't know if it's a permanent fix though

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you've already solved this, but I had a similar problem when I tried to run or debug my code, so I did this: [Visual Studio (VS-code) code terminal is failing to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-vs-code-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch)

Then restart VS Code and it worked!! I hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).