How to fix "com.sun.jdi.connect.transporttimeoutexception" in VS Code (Java)
I am working in Java and JavaFX in VSCode for Windows.
I had to reinstall VS Code, redownload Java, revert to an older version of Language support and reinstall the extensions trying to fix another problem regarding not being able to connect to Java Language Support Servers (which I believe I've solved) but am now unable to launch the debugger.
I am getting a pop-up window saying:
Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. 
Reason: com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException

It prompts me to open my launch.json.
I'm assuming that there is some setting or path that got messed up or needs to be changed but I have no idea what.
I tried reinstalling VS Code, running without debugging, reverting to an older version of my debugger, and remaking my launch.json file. None of these seemed to have an impact on it.

I think this may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131243/failed-to-launch-debuggee-in-terminal
