# Can't get any code to run on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

[Print-Screen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTkcA.png)

Hello everyone, I'm new to programming and encountering an issue with my Visual Studio Code (VSC). I've attempted various solutions I discovered online, which addressed similar problems to mine, but unfortunately, none have proven effective.

Is anyone familiar with what's happening? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

some of the solutions I tried :
https://www.reddit.com/r/raylib/comments/121m8of/guys_pls_help_i_get_this_error_whenever_i_try_to/
[Visual Studio Code terminal is failing to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch)

update: I reset my PC to its factory configuration and attempted to reinstall VSC. However, I encountered the same error. I followed the instructions to install MinGW and now I'm facing a different error. Here's a screenshot of the second error [Print-Screen of my second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQXVQ.png)

Comment: first remove all spaces from your filepath/filename, not likely you have gcc stored in your project directory